# Set of steps that cannot be implemented on a Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

Is there an example of a "set of steps" that we thought was an algorithm, but later was shown not to be an algorithm because it could not be implemented on a Turing machine?

Answer (score 2):

The [Church–Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) states that every algorithm can be implemented on a Turing machine. It has stood the test of time. In particular, I believe that the answer to your question is negative.

The appearance of quantum algorithms, in particular Shor's factorization algorithm, has called into question the *efficient* Church–Turing thesis (sometimes known as the Cook–Karp thesis), which states that $\mathsf{P}$ captures the class of efficiently solvable problems; but quantum computers are known to compute the same class of languages as classical computers.

Answer (score 2):

When Hilbert set out his famous list of problems in 1900, the [tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) was posed as follows:

> "Given a Diophantine equation with any number of unknown quantities and with rational integral numerical coefficients: To devise a process according to which it can be determined in a finite number of operations whether the equation is solvable in rational integers"

This wording strongly suggests that Hilbert (and the majority of the mathematical community at that time) believed a "set of steps" existed that could solve any system of Diophantine equations, given enough time and resources. Hilbert's challenge was to "devise" i.e. to formally document this process in a "finite number of operations" - what in modern terms we would call an algorithm.

We now know that Hilbert's tenth problem is [undecideable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems), and the general algorithm that Hilbert was asking for does not exist.